# Activity not starting in motorola

Tags: android, image

I am trying download image but when I am selecting the resolution it's not working, in redmi, one plus device it's working fine

in Motorola, pixel it's not working well

check issue here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/spdRH.jpg

getting this error in Motorola

```
06-21 16:25:07.294 1834-5281/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 14262:com.rayvatapps.inspiquo/u0a238 (adj 0): error during init
06-21 16:25:07.309 1834-5281/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 14275:com.rayvatapps.inspiquo/u0a238 for activity com.rayvatapps.inspiquo/.PreviewActivity
06-21 16:25:07.354 1834-5356/? W/ActivityManager: Exception in new application when starting activity com.rayvatapps.inspiquo/.PreviewActivity
    android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 699432 bytes
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:615)
        at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleLaunchActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:893)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1326)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:883)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:6816)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:6884)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:552)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2906)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
06-21 16:25:07.355 1834-5356/? E/ActivityManager: Exception thrown launching activities in ProcessRecord{8d51d61 14275:com.rayvatapps.inspiquo/u0a238}
    android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 699432 bytes
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:615)
        at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleLaunchActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:893)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1326)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:883)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:6816)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:6884)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:552)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2906)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
```

this is my code

**PreviewActivity.java**

```
/**
 * Created by mitesh on 18/06/18.
 */
public class PreviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    View mDecorView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    RelativeLayout lnimg;
    TextView tvquote,tvauthor;
    ImageView imgquote,download,loader;
    LinearLayout lnwallpaper,lndownload;
    RelativeLayout main;
    View viewpreview;
    String quote,author,imgpath;
    int imgtype,count;
    Mysql mySql;
    ArrayList<String> imageList;
    final Random rnd = new Random();
    String main_url="http://inspiquo.rayvatapps.com/v2/api.php?request=";
    String JSON_IMG_URL = main_url+"getbackgrounds";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preview);
        mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        hideSystemUI();
        imageList = new ArrayList<String>();
        checkconnection();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras == null) {
            quote="";
            author="";
            imgpath="";
            imgtype=0;
        } else {
            quote= extras.getString("quote");
            author= extras.getString("author");
            imgpath= extras.getString("imgpath");
            imgtype= extras.getInt("type");
            Log.e("Quote "+ quote," author "+author +" type "+imgtype);
        }
        lnimg=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.lnimg);
        imgquote=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgquote);
        download=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgsave);
        loader=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgloader);
        lndownload=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lndownload);
        lnwallpaper=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lnsetwallpaper);
        main=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnmain);
        tvquote=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.quote);
        tvauthor=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.author);
        viewpreview=(View) findViewById(R.id.viewpreview);
//        viewpreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HKNova-Medium.ttf");
        tvquote.setTypeface(tf);
        byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

        tvquote.setText(quote);
        tvauthor.setText(author);
        if(imgtype==2)
        {
            main.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FCFEFC"));
            Glide.with(PreviewActivity.this)
                    .load(R.drawable.download_loader)
                    .into(new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(loader));

            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(imgpath)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .error(R.color.black)
                    .into(imgquote);
            imgquote.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            tvquote.setTextSize(30);
            tvauthor.setTextSize(20);
            lnwallpaper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromLayout();
                    saveImageToExternalStorage(bitmap);
                }
            }, 2000);
            /*Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromLayout();
            saveImageToExternalStorage(bitmap);*/
        }
        else if(imgtype==3)
        {
            Glide.with(PreviewActivity.this)
                    .load(R.drawable.time_loader)
                    .into(new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(loader));
            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(imgpath)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .error(R.color.black)
                    .into(imgquote);
            imgquote.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            tvquote.setTextSize(30);
            tvauthor.setTextSize(20);
            lndownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                lnimg.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                lnimg.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bitmap = lnimg.getDrawingCache();

                try {
                    setWallpaper(bitmap);
                    Toast.makeText(PreviewActivity.this, "Wallpaper set Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
            }, 3000);
        }
        else
        {
            main.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FCFEFC"));
            Glide.with(PreviewActivity.this)
                    .load(R.drawable.download_loader)
                    .into(new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(loader));
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = viewpreview.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = imgquote.getHeight();
            params.width = imgquote.getWidth();
            viewpreview.setLayoutParams(params);
            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(byteArray)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .fitCenter()
                    .error(R.color.black)
                    .into(imgquote);
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromLayout();
                    saveImageToExternalStorage(bitmap);                
            }
            }, 2000);   
        }
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromLayout() {
        Bitmap mBitmap = null;
        try {
            if (mBitmap != null) {
                mBitmap.recycle();
            }
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(lnimg.getWidth(), lnimg.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            lnimg.draw(canvas);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
            return mBitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.gc();
        }
        return mBitmap;
    }
    private void saveImageToExternalStorage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/Inspiquo/Inspiquo Images");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(PreviewActivity.this, new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    }
                });
        Toast.makeText(PreviewActivity.this, "Saved to Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
    private void hideSystemUI() {
        mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION 
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN 
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
    }
}
```

I am just trying to do is get screen resolution and set an image and download as portrait or landscape

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the crash log it seems you are trying to pass bitmap via Intent

android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 699432 bytes

You can try scaling the image before passing it to Intent
Or you can save the image on file system and pass the URI.
See if it helps.
Ankit

Comment: thank you for your quick response it's working well now